# Как связать select и input text

Tags: javascript, html

Есть примерно такая структура.Как можно сделать,чтобы выбор `option` прописывался в `input`?
Допустим,стоит инпут,возле него селект,допустим,пользователь выбрал `option` 169 (Российская федерация),и нужно чтобы значение ячейки (в случае с option 169 - Российская федерация) прописалось в инпут (value).И так со всеми остальными,то есть если выбрал допустим "Австрия",то чтобы в инпут (value) прописался "Австрия" и т.д.Как это можно реализовать?
Если надо,список можно укоротить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю так вы хотели.

```js
function update(e, targetId) {
  let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  let ob = e.options[e.selectedIndex]
  target.value = `${ob.value} - ${ob.text}`
}
```

```html
<input id="bdF17" class="manFlOth3" value="" name="sa3" maxlength="100" type="text">

<select class="manFlaCountry" id="siF6" name="country" onchange="update(event.target, 'bdF17')">
  <option value="148" selected class="top">Нидерланды</option>
  <option value="169" class="top">Российская Федерация</option>
  <option value="204" class="top">Украина</option>
  <option value="31" class="top">Беларусь</option>
  <option value="111" class="top">Казахстан</option>
  <option value="12">Австралия</option>
  <option value="11">Австрия</option>
  <option value="14">Азербайджан</option>
  <option value="5">Албания</option>
  <option value="55">Алжир</option>
  <option value="10">Американское Самоа</option>
  <option value="221">Ангилья</option>
  <option value="94">Английская Индийская Океаническая Территория</option>
  <option value="8">Ангола</option>
  <option value="1">Андорра</option>
  <option value="222">Антарктика</option>
  <option value="4">Антигуа и Барбуда</option>
  <option value="7">Антильский Остров Нидерландов</option>
  <option value="186">Арабская Республика Суринам</option>
  <option value="9">Аргентина</option>
  <option value="6">Армения</option>
  <option value="13">Аруба</option>
  <option value="3">Афганистан</option>
  <option value="28">Багамский Остров</option>
  <option value="17">Бангладеш</option>
  <option value="16">Барбадос</option>
  <option value="21">Бахрейн</option>
  <option value="32">Белиз</option>
  <option value="18">Бельгия</option>
  <option value="23">Бенин</option>
  <option value="20">Болгария</option>
  <option value="26">Боливия</option>
  <option value="15">Босния и Герцеговина</option>
  <option value="30">Ботсвана</option>
  <option value="27">Бразилия</option>
  <option value="25">Бруней</option>
  <option value="19">Буркина Фасо</option>
  <option value="22">Бурунди</option>
  <option value="29">Бутан</option>
  <option value="215">Вануату</option>
  <option value="209">Ватикан</option>
  <option value="69">Великобритания</option>
  <option value="89">Венгрия</option>
  <option value="211">Венесуэла</option>
  <option value="212">Виргинские острова (UK)</option>
  <option value="195">Восточный Тимор</option>
  <option value="214">Вьетнам</option>
  <option value="68">Габон</option>
  <option value="88">Гаити</option>
  <option value="84">Гайана</option>
  <option value="76">Гамбия</option>
  <option value="73">Гана</option>
  <option value="78">Гваделупа</option>
  <option value="81">Гватемала</option>
  <option value="77">Гвинея</option>
  <option value="83">Гвинея-Бисау</option>
  <option value="50">Германия</option>
  <option value="235">Гернси и Олдерни</option>
  <option value="74">Гибралтар</option>
  <option value="85">Гонг-Конг</option>
  <option value="86">Гондурас</option>
  <option value="70">Гренада</option>
  <option value="75">Гренландия</option>
  <option value="80">Греция</option>
  <option value="71">Грузия</option>
  <option value="52">Дания</option>
  <option value="34">Дем. республика Конго</option>
  <option value="51">Джибути</option>
  <option value="53">Доминика</option>
  <option value="54">Доминиканская Республика</option>
  <option value="58">Египет</option>
  <option value="59">Еритреа</option>
  <option value="219">Замбия</option>
  <option value="220">Зимбабве</option>
  <option value="92">Израиль</option>
  <option value="93">Индия</option>
  <option value="90">Индонезия</option>
  <option value="100">Иордания</option>
  <option value="95">Ирак</option>
  <option value="96">Иран</option>
  <option value="91">Ирландия</option>
  <option value="97">Исландия</option>
  <option value="60">Испания</option>
  <option value="98">Италия</option>
  <option value="217">Йемен</option>
  <option value="47">Кабо Верде</option>
  <option value="110">Каймановы острова</option>
  <option value="104">Камбоджа</option>
  <option value="41">Камерун</option>
  <option value="33">Канада</option>
  <option value="166">Катар</option>
  <option value="102">Кения</option>
  <option value="48">Кипр</option>
  <option value="105">Кирибати</option>
  <option value="42">Китай</option>
  <option value="43">Колумбия</option>
  <option value="106">Комморские острова</option>
  <option value="36">Конго</option>
  <option value="108">Корея</option>
  <option value="44">Коста Рика</option>
  <option value="38">Кот Д'ивуар</option>
  <option value="46">Куба</option>
  <option value="109">Кувейт</option>
  <option value="103">Кыргызстан</option>
  <option value="112">Лаос</option>
  <option value="121">Латвия</option>
  <option value="118">Лесото</option>
  <option value="117">Либерия</option>
  <option value="113">Ливан</option>
  <option value="122">Ливийская Арабская республика Джамахирия</option>
  <option value="119">Литва</option>
  <option value="115">Лихтенштейн</option>
  <option value="120">Люксембург</option>
  <option value="137">Маврикий</option>
  <option value="135">Мавритания</option>
  <option value="126">Мадагаскар</option>
  <option value="132">Макао</option>
  <option value="128">Македония</option>
  <option value="139">Малави</option>
  <option value="141">Малайзия</option>
  <option value="129">Мали</option>
  <option value="138">Мальдивы</option>
  <option value="136">Мальта</option>
  <option value="123">Марокко</option>
  <option value="134">Мартиника</option>
  <option value="127">Маршалловы острова</option>
  <option value="140">Мексика</option>
  <option value="142">Мозамбик</option>
  <option value="125">Молдова</option>
  <option value="124">Монако</option>
  <option value="131">Монголия</option>
  <option value="229">Монтсеррат</option>
  <option value="130">Мьянмар</option>
  <option value="143">Намибия</option>
  <option value="151">Науру</option>
  <option value="150">Непал</option>
  <option value="145">Нигер</option>
  <option value="146">Нигерия</option>
  <option value="147">Никарагуа</option>
  <option value="231">Ниуэ</option>
  <option value="152">Новая Зеландия</option>
  <option value="144">Новая Каледония</option>
  <option value="149">Норвегия</option>
  <option value="2">Объединенные Арабские Эмираты</option>
  <option value="153">Оман</option>
  <option value="237">Остров Святой Елены</option>
  <option value="39">Острова Кука</option>
  <option value="233">Острова Уоллис и Футуна</option>
  <option value="66">Острова Фару</option>
  <option value="159">Пакистан</option>
  <option value="164">Палау</option>
  <option value="162">Палестинская Территория</option>
  <option value="154">Панама</option>
  <option value="157">Папуа Новая Гвинея</option>
  <option value="165">Парагвай</option>
  <option value="155">Перу</option>
  <option value="160">Польша</option>
  <option value="163">Португалия</option>
  <option value="167">Реюнион</option>
  <option value="170">Руанда</option>
  <option value="168">Румыния</option>
  <option value="216">Самоа</option>
  <option value="180">Сан-Марино</option>
  <option value="184">Сан-Томе и Принсипи</option>
  <option value="171">Саудовская Аравия</option>
  <option value="187">Свазиленд</option>
  <option value="210">Святого Винсента и Гренадины</option>
  <option value="107">Святой Киттс и Невис</option>
  <option value="236">Северная Корея</option>
  <option value="173">Сейшелы</option>
  <option value="181">Сенегал</option>
  <option value="114">Сент-Люсия</option>
  <option value="45">Сербия</option>
  <option value="176">Сингапур</option>
  <option value="178">Словакия</option>
  <option value="177">Словения</option>
  <option value="206">Соединенные Штаты</option>
  <option value="172">Соломоновы острова</option>
  <option value="182">Сомали</option>
  <option value="174">Судан</option>
  <option value="183">Суринам</option>
  <option value="179">Сьерра-Леоне</option>
  <option value="193">Таджикистан</option>
  <option value="192">Таиланд</option>
  <option value="202">Тайвань</option>
  <option value="194">Такелау</option>
  <option value="203">Танзания</option>
  <option value="191">Того</option>
  <option value="198">Тонга</option>
  <option value="200">Тринидад и Тобаго</option>
  <option value="201">Тувалу</option>
  <option value="197">Тунис</option>
  <option value="196">Туркменистан</option>
  <option value="199">Турция</option>
  <option value="205">Уганда</option>
  <option value="208">Узбекистан</option>
  <option value="207">Уругвай</option>
  <option value="65">Федеративные Штаты Микронезия</option>
  <option value="63">Фиджи</option>
  <option value="158">Филиппины</option>
  <option value="62">Финляндия</option>
  <option value="64">Фолклендские острова</option>
  <option value="67">Франция</option>
  <option value="72">Французская Гвиана</option>
  <option value="156">Французская Полинезия</option>
  <option value="87">Хорватия</option>
  <option value="35">Центральная Африканская Республика</option>
  <option value="189">Чад</option>
  <option value="228">Черногория</option>
  <option value="49">Чешская Республика</option>
  <option value="40">Чили</option>
  <option value="37">Швейцария</option>
  <option value="175">Швеция</option>
  <option value="116">Шри-Ланка</option>
  <option value="56">Эквадор</option>
  <option value="79">Экваториальная Гвинея</option>
  <option value="185">Эль Сальвадор</option>
  <option value="57">Эстония</option>
  <option value="61">Эфиопия</option>
  <option value="218">Южная Африка</option>
  <option value="99">Ямайка</option>
  <option value="101">Япония</option>
</select>
```

```js
function update(e, targetId) {
  let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  let ob = e.options[e.selectedIndex]
  target.value = `${ob.value} - ${ob.text}`
}
```

```js
function update(e, targetId) {
  let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  let ob = e;
  target.value = `${ob.value} - ${ob.id}`
}
```

```html
<input id="bdF17" class="manFlOth3" value="" name="sa3" maxlength="100" type="text">

<div>
  <input type="radio" onchange="update(event.target, 'bdF17')" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="email">
  <label for="contactChoice1">Email</label>

  <input type="radio" onchange="update(event.target, 'bdF17')" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="phone">
  <label for="contactChoice2">Phone</label>

  <input type="radio" onchange="update(event.target, 'bdF17')" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="mail">
  <label for="contactChoice3">Mail</label>
</div>
```

Comment: а вы бы не подсказали как это сделать с radio?например,есть такой же инпут и 2 радио кнопки:да и нет,и как можно сделать чтобы например при нажатии на "Нет" поле очищалось,а при нажатии на "Да" в поле,например написалось бы слово "Да"?

Comment: кстати,будет ли этот скрипт работать с jQuery 1.12.4?

Comment: работать будет, это нативный js, по radio тоже самое только навесить ивент на каждую кнопку

Comment: если можно подробнее...

Comment: добавил выше пример

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: упс..я добавил на страницу 2 скрипта (которые вы отпраили),но,они перебивают друг друга,как это можно исправить?      <script>function update(e, targetId) {
 let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
 let ob = e.options[e.selectedIndex]
 target.value = `${ob.text}`
}</script>
 <script>function update(e, targetId) {
  let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  let ob = e;
  target.value = `${ob.value}`
}
</script>

Comment: назовите  их update и update2

Comment: а вы бы не подсказали еще по одному вопросу?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1027187/